# Performance counter for Number of ports in use for making a connection

Tags: windows, performance, netstat, perfmon

I am using this command to identify the number of ports in use

```
netstat -anob
```

Is there a performance counter that i can use so that i can plot a graph on perfmon and see what happens when the number of requests per second increases?

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote, this is a sensible question as perf counters are easier to monitor over time

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you'll want to look at TCPv4/Connections Established. Note that this will be different than the IIS perf counters - not sure if you want system or IIS.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787094(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I would like to have both system and IIS perf counters for the connections that are established. i generally use .NET CLR networking 4.0.0.0/Connections Established performance counter. How is different from TCPv4/Connections Established? I dont see any data getting pushed to TCPv4/Connections Established or TCPv6/Connections Established. Do you know how can i enable them?